# Google Classroom Share Button: IE Errors

Tags: internet-explorer, google-classroom

A javascript error is being thrown when clicking on the Classroom Share button in IE (I’ve tested in IE10 and IE11). This is reproducible in our production site, as well as on the Classroom API page @ https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton?hl=en. I’ve attached a screenshot. I could be wrong, but It seems like this started happening sometime in December 2015.

To reproduce the issue, clear the browser cache/cookies, and make sure you sign in to Google as a teacher that can post to Google Classroom. You should now be able to see the javascript error. In order to see it again, you'll have to clear cache/cookies.

The code I've used to implement the button is quite similar to that on the sample page @ https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton?hl=en. As mentioned before, the issues also happens on their sample page. I'm curious if anyone else has seen this. I've also reached to Google about the issue.

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="g-sharetoclassroom" data-size="32" data-url="..." ></div>
</div>
<script>
  gapi.sharetoclassroom.go("content");
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code and how you implemented the Classroom Share button?

Comment: I've added some sample code to my question.

Comment: weird, the sample button in the Classroom API page is working fine. tried it over IE11. is your Internet connectivity behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to Google, it appears they've identified an issue, and are working to resolve it.

Comment: They've fixed the issue.